# Templates not being processed - tags are displayed

Tags: templates

I've recently moved several ExpressionEngine sites from one server to another. Most are fine but one is now displaying template tags on the site itself. I don't really know where to start with this as I don't often work with EE. I've tried clearing the cache and making sure the file paths are correct. There are no errors in the server's error log.

I am looking for some help to diagnose this problem and find out what might need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Common problems rendering a template include:

Malformed tags:

```
{exp:channel:entwies channel="blog_posts"} ...
```

PHP intermingled where it doesn't work or has syntax errors:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel=<?php echo "\"" . $channel_name . "\""?>} ...
```

Tags embedded in tags embedded in tags eventually causing a parse order issue, or a tag space error:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{exp:channel:category_heading}{if "{category_name}" == 'category 1'}-{category_name}{if:else}|{category_name}{/exp:channel:category_heading}{/if}"} ...
```

I hope some of this helps.

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to check for would be to make sure that the template hasn't somehow been set to be a static template.

Answer (score 0):

Old post which the OP seems to have dropped, but for anyone stumbling on this for their own purposes…

To build on what Mark mentioned, and since OP noted that he's not overly familiar with ExpressionEngine, the location of the 'static' template setting is as pictured below (note the Breadcrumb trail at the top of the image to get to the template's settings).

The two suggestions, that a) the template is set to static or b) there's a simple typo causing EE's tags to not parse, are two excellent places to start.

[image: Static Template setting, ExpressionEngine]